# easiest way to fill in holes on distressed font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Using a font with some distressing.  I need to remove the distress holes in the font.  When i try to get rid of the little holes, it's also getting rid of the large holes that make the letters o and f.  Is there an easy way to do this that I'm totally overlooking?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I apologize.  I did several searches prior to posting and couldn't find it.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just **Right Click → Release Compound Path** and that will probably do the trick for you.

Though that will also release the holes from the letters and you will be left with a bunch of unnecessary paths.

To fix that you can then select the 4 holes + the base shape and then **Right Click → Make Compound Path** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) and then just select all and use the pathfinder *Unite* option.

---

Another way I can think of is to use the pen tool to draw some paths above the unwanted holes (very rough shape - no precision needed) and then use pathfinder unite to merge them all together.

---

You can also use the *Shape Builder Tool* and **Click + Drag** on areas to merge together.